# Implement Pushnotification using Phonegap-push-plugin

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I have installed Phonegap-push-plugin in my app and i see that two files are added to my project.PushPlugin.h and Appdelegate+notification.h
Is i need to add delegate for pushnotification in my Appdelegate.h file?
How to use this new plugin for implementing pushnotification in the app?

Answer (score 0):

there are some steps to configure push notification in your application

App ID Configurations and Certificates

1.1. Issuing a Certificate Signing Request

1.2. Creating an App ID

1.3. Configuring Push Notifications for the App ID

1.4 Creating a Private Key

1.5 Creating a Provisioning Profile

Than you can go for Push notification Plugin integration

This is how you can register for Push notification.

```
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
 pushNotification.register(
  tokenHandler,
  errorHandler,
  {
   'badge':'false',
   'sound':'false',
   'alert':'true',
   'ecb':'onNotificationAPN'
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments . can u please explain the remaining steps especially handling in appdelegate for push notification

Comment: Hey If you are talking about hybrid app means you have to handle everything from your javascript side. Download that zip file and check they given example for that as well

Comment: Hi which zip file you are mentioning.My dought is, Is it necessary to add any delegate method for pushnotification in native appdelegate.h file. Since new plugin also include Appdelegate+Notification.h and .m file. Any sample code based on new push plugin ?